# MongoDb aggregation project only json values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I have an aggregation query, and I'm getting a response as

```
{ "elements" : [ "APP_TC1", "APP_TC2", "APP_TC4"] }
```

But instead of mapping those aggregation results into an object like

```
Class elements{

private List<String> elements;

}
```

Will I get the results straight as a string array? I mean, I need the aggregation result as

```
[ "APP_TC1", "APP_TC2", "APP_TC4"]
```

Comment: No you cannot. Aggregation only returns bson document rather than just array of strings

Comment: Can you post the aggregation query?